# How can I pass props to img src in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue programming and have just written a simple script that fetches book metadata via an Axios interface and then displays a list of books. it works great.

But now I wanted to display a single book with a template.

```
 Vue.component('my-book', {
  props: ['title','body','coverimg'],
  template: `
    <li class="row-animated border-bo-dd mb10 pb10 imgshadow">{{ title }}{{ body }}{{ coverimg }}
    <img class="pointer fl mr10"  src= "{{coverimg}}" />
    </li>
  `
});

<my-book
  v-for="book in bookFeed"
  v-bind:key="book.id"
  v-bind:title="book.node_title"
  v-bind:body="book.body"
  v-bind:path="book.path"
  v-bind:coverimg="book.medium_img" >
</my-book>
```

In the template, I output the passed props for testing purposes. But what I can't do is assign coverimg as a URl to the img tag. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

**You can either use the shorthand `:` or `v-bind`** to bind attribute

It should be like this

```
<img class="pointer fl mr10"  :src= "coverimg" />
```

or

```
<img class="pointer fl mr10"  v-bind:src= "coverimg" />
```